# How to copy full vim/vi remote file content to my local clipboard

Tags: linux, vim, vi, clipboard

I am having a file in the remote machine ( connected with customized ssh not Normal ssh ) .I do not have a way to copy/move the file to my local ( No scp allowed and no other connectivity ) .I am thinking of copying the whole file's content (from vi) to my local clipboard and paste it wherever i want.

I have tried

```
<VisualMode> "*y
```

and

```
<VisualMode> "+y
```

but nothing copied to my clipboard.

I have tried couple of `:noremap "*y` commands too but none worked.

The remote file has around 5000 lines.So i don't want to use **mouse** after `cat file` or by using `more file` or `less file` and copy that by selecting.

Remote Machine : Linux
Local Machine : Windows

Any other method available ?

Comment: Does your Vim have clipboard support? Does that work if you try it in a local file?

Comment: I tried executing `if has('clipboard')` ... nothing happened.No output.

Comment: `vim --version | grep clipboard` gives you + or - clipboard?

Comment: yeah its , `-clipboard`  , so cannot do anything with clipboard?

Comment: No, but yes! You can compile it with that option enabled or check your distribution packages for one that enables it. For example, `vim-gnome` in Debian.

Comment: Do you have X11 forwarding on the Windows machine? You could then probably use `xclip` on the linux machine a la `xclip -sel clip < /path/to/file/to/copy`.  I've done this linux to linux, but haven't tried from a Windows machine. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152362/how-to-send-data-to-local-clipboard-from-a-remote-ssh-session) may also have some hints.

Comment: @Quasímodo : Thats highly secured production environment  and the rest you know.

Comment: @einfeyn496 : No X11 :(

Comment: Does your `ssh` allow you to do the equivalent of `ssh remote 'cat thefile' >localcopy`?

Comment: @Kusalananda : I did exactly the same , but since it is customized ssh we cannot do anything like usually we do in ssh.

Comment: Just in case, does the environment  allow outgoing connections to internet over https ?

Comment: By any chance could you use `tmux` in a terminal, and copy between two panes, one being the remote session?

Comment: @Tagwint : I thought about that too and tried sending email but no outgoing connections at all...

Comment: @einfeyn496 : Nothing can be installed or modified on both local and remote machine...Thats the problem ...

Comment: Just for completion: email port may be closed, but 443 can be available
and perhaps there can be some internal proxy. 
If that happen to be the case you could use public pastebin services.

Comment: @Tagwint : No Tagwint..thats very secured environment...

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar I see.
as a last resort, if that's possible with your terminal app  you could set the font size down to smallest possible (mine alllows ~400 lines of text on one screen) that would make possible to grab the content with mouse  in (5000/400) ~ 12 actions only :)

Comment: @Tagwint : That's a very nice idea...i will try that for next file. Thank you so much...

Comment: Thank you so much for  all your suggestions . But i did it in a vague way by changing the new line to some character that does not in file using `tr`  , since the file has a small word or group of words in each line. And then copied the whole content in one shot since the content size decreased.